# RAW image data to Android Bitmap

Tags: java, android, image, networking, bitmap

I've been working on an extension of a current application to stream webcam data to an Android device. I can obtain the raw image data, in the form of a RGB byte array. The color space is sRGB. I need to send that array over the network to an Android client, who constructs it into a Bitmap image to display on the screen. My problem is that the color data is skewed. The arrays have the same hashcode before and after being sent, so I'm positive this isn't a data loss problem. I've attached a [sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exqJH.png) of how the color looks, you can see that skin tones and darker colors reconstruct okay, but lighter colors end up with a lot of yellow/red artifacts.

Server (Windows 10) code :

```
while(socket.isConnected()) {


        byte[] bufferArray = new byte[width * height * 3];

        ByteBuffer buff = cam.getImageBytes();

        for(int i = 0; i < bufferArray.length; i++) {

            bufferArray[i] = buff.get();

        }

        out.write(bufferArray);
        out.flush();

    }
```

Client (Android) code :

```
while(socket.isConnected()) {

            int[] colors = new int[width * height];
            byte[] pixels = new byte[(width * height) * 3];

            int bytesRead = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < (width * height * 3); i++) {
                int temp = in.read();
                if(temp == -1) {
                    Log.d("WARNING", "Problem reading");
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    pixels[i] = (byte) temp;
                    bytesRead++;
                }
            }

            int colorIndex = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i += 3 ) {

                int r = pixels[i];
                int g = pixels[i + 1];
                int b = pixels[i + 2];

                colors[colorIndex] = Color.rgb( r, g, b);
                colorIndex++;
            }

            Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(colors, width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            publishProgress(image);

        }
```

The cam.getImageBytes() is from an external library, but I have tested it and it works properly. Reconstructing the RAW data into a BufferedImage works perfectly, using the code :

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
image.getRaster().setPixels(0,0,width,height, pixels);
```

But, of course, BufferedImages are not supported on Android.

I'm about to tear my hair out with this one, I've tried everything I can think of, so any and all insight would be extremely helpful!

Comment: What is the issue? I don't see a question.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity - the problem is addressed in the first paragraph, and the fact that the colors are not being represented properly. All of the yellow/red artifacts.